# Setup Continuous Integration with Visual Studio 2010 and Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, continuous-integration

Is there a good guide on how to do this with these two exact pieces of software? I have found a lot of generalized CI setup guides, but none involving these two exact components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS makes setting up a continuous integration server very simple.  You will first need to [create a new TFS project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhedaeb2(v=vs.80).aspx).  Then you need to configure Visual Studio to [use your new project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181474(v=vs.80).aspx).  Finally, you can setup a build for the project within TFS.  There is a pretty good blog [post](http://www.theabsentmindedcoder.com/2010/02/creating-my-first-tfs-2010-build.html) about how to do it.  The important step is setting the build trigger:

[image]

You can set various build triggers, including a continuous schedule.  Obviously, you can get much more complex with the build definition.  Deployment options, config options, but hopefully this will be enough to get you started.